# deprecation logger in hibernate 5

Tags: java, hibernate, log4j

We are migrating to Hibernate 5. in the migration guide [Migrating from 4.3 to 5.0](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.0/migration-guide.adoc#deprecations) it says a new logger has been added to consolidate all the deprecated stuff. It has no further explanation. I have also checked the user guide. It's not described there either. I searched through the code and came up with the below configuration but still, everything is being logged to the root logger.

```
log4j.rootLogger =  INFO, File
log4j.rootCategory = INFO, File

log4j.appender.File=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.File.File=../logs/testEngine.log
log4j.appender.File.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.File.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.File.append=true
log4j.appender.File.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.File.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p [%t] %c: %m%n

log4j.logger.org.hibernate.orm.deprecation = TRACE, deprecation

log4j.additivity.org.hibernate.orm.deprecation = false


log4j.appender.deprecation=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.deprecation.File=../logs/TestEngine_deprecation.log
log4j.appender.deprecation.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.deprecation.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.deprecation.append=true
log4j.appender.deprecation.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.deprecation.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p [%t] %c: %m%n
```

Could you please let me know what am I doing wrong?